# How does wallet connect work under the hood?

Tags: walletconnect

If I want to connect my [safe](https://gnosis-safe.io/) multi-sig wallet to a dapp, I will use [wallet connect](https://walletconnect.com/) - but what is it doing under the hood?

Web browser wallets like [metamask](https://metamask.io/) work by sticking an `ethereum` object onto the window, and dapps can access it from the `window` object [in their javascript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdsYCkUWrgQ&lc=Ugyyaonwe_CqznZzOuN4AaABAg.9m16AwlS8V29m8WMoJ7nCM). The `ethereum` object has a number of APIs to interact with Metamask and submit transactions for users to approve.

But, what is wallet connect doing?